# Android Emulator - Unable to perform operation after login to the app

Tags: appium, appium-android

I have an app and i am trying to use the emulators using android studio. The setup is all done, and i am able to start the execution. However, after performing the login step, appium is unable to do the findelement on the objects that are present.

already tried using capability like automationName: UIautomator2 and appium 
Appium logs show that the findelement is not returning anything but the objects are present and it seems to work on physical device

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend you download [Appium Desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop). It's a bundled server and UI inspector. It should help you with your teething problems.

Comment: I tried using this but was unable to create appium grid with it